# The multi-part identifier "inserted.SECTION_ID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

In my application, data should be entered using a Web interface. If I enter same section id, then error message should be displayed.

I have MEETING table with SECTION_ID
When I try to do trigger, I got an error

```
    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fourone, Line 7
    The multi-part identifier "inserted.SECTION_ID" could not be bound.
```

---

```
    Create trigger fourone
    On MEETING
    for Insert
    As

    IF( exists (select * from MEETING WHERE MEETING.SECTION_ID = inserted.SECTION_ID )) 
    BEGIN   
        raiserror('ERRORRRRRRRR',15,1);
    END
```

---

What am I missing?
Can you guys give me any advice?

Comment: Why not `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MEETING_SECTION ON MEETING (SECTION_ID)` instead of a trigger? (Although this would also prevent a single insert containing two rows with identical `SECTION_ID` values, which your current trigger and the answers will still allow)

Comment: I just want to try to do the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the inserted table in a JOIN like this:

```
IF( exists (select * from MEETING 
               JOIN inserted ON MEETING.SECTION_ID = inserted.SECTION_ID )) 
BEGIN
    raiserror('ERRORRRRRRRR',15,1);
END
```

Comment: Thank you. I fix the error, but I get another error. When I enter any value, then it's always displayed the error message. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @JayLee - you're defining a `for insert` a.k.a `after insert` trigger - by the time it executes, all rows in `inserted` are also present in the base table.

Comment: thank you for give me advice, but if i use "instead of insert", then it does not enter any value in the meeting table.

Comment: @JayLee - if you write an `instead of insert` trigger, then *you* have to perform the actual insert into the base table, within the body of your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement should be like this:

```
IF(EXISTS(
        SELECT 
          NULL 
        FROM 
          MEETING 
        WHERE EXISTS
          (
             SELECT 
               NULL 
             FROM 
               inserted 
             WHERE 
               inserted.SECTION_ID=MEETING.SECTION_ID
          )
    )
BEGIN
  raiserror('ERRORRRRRRRR',15,1);
END
```

On msdn it says:

> DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables.
>   They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is
>   defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The
>   deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the
>   rows that may be changed by the user action. For example, to retrieve
>   all values in the deleted table, use

See reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: I like your answer, other than the switch from `SELECT *` to `SELECT NULL` in the `EXISTS` - back in the dark ages of SQL Server (pre 7.0, I believe), that might have been useful. But the optimizer has known for a long time that `SELECT *` within an `EXISTS` just needs to determine if there are rows - it doesn't expand it into a full set of columns, nor even perform a schema lookup, I believe.

Comment: Thank you. I fix the error, but I get another error. When I enter any value, then it's always displayed the error message.

Comment: I did not know that. I think that linq-to-sql still translates the contains to `SELECT NULL` not `SELECT *`. I belive it do not mather if you `SELECT NULL` or evan `SELECT 'doh!` the query optimizer just care about the condition. I think it is just a style of writing the syntax